# What is the function of the beta symbol (ß) in PHP

Tags: php

I saw it on [phpgolf](http://www.phpgolf.org/tips). A few examples they provided use it.

```
<?for($a='This is a string';$b=$a[$i++];)$b==' '?:$c[$b&=ß]=$b;sort($c);echo join($c,"\n");
```

I've gone thru [several](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=what%20does%20%C3%9F%20mean%20in%20php&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#channel=fs&q=what%20does%20%C3%9F%20%28%20beta%20symbol%29%20mean%20in%20php) [pages](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=what++does+%C3%9F+mean+in+mpm&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#channel=fs&q=what++does+%C3%9F+mean+in+php) of google results and even searched SO. Couldn't find it.

Comment: It's nothing special in PHP: code will treat it as a constant, and if it doesn't exist as a constant then it will be treated as a literal string (and appropriate notices displayed if notices are enabled)

Comment: No, you can't edit my question. It's codegolf. The code is supposed  to be compressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's not a beta char, it's a "sharp s" in german (see `ß` vs `β`). The answer is directly on the [page you linked](http://www.phpgolf.org/tips):

> Bitwise inversion (~)
>   One of the most used bitwise operators. Especially for the use with strings. Since this operator makes it possible to save bytes on whitespace and characters that have a meaning to PHP.
>   Here a listing of the most important chars
>
> [...]
>
> - Space (char 32) -> ~ß

So, the character represents a space.